# "Bad File Descriptor" error using Python/CGI in IIS 6.1

Tags: iis-6, python, cgi, stdin

**Background**:

I've attempted (strong emphasis on "attempt") to set up an application via IIS (6.1, Windows Server 2008 R1) that routes all requests through a python script.  The end goal was to create a very light-weight API on the server.

Basically, I took the following steps:

1. Added CGI feature to windows
2. Created a new Application under the **Default Web Site**
3. Added a handler mapping that accepts `*` and runs `c:\Python27\python.exe -u "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\testapi\cgiadapter.py"`
4. Set the virtual directory of the application to `testapi`
5. Set the physical path of the application to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\testapi`

To do a *basic* test, the following script was tested and works:

```
import cgi, cgitb

# Detailed error logging to screen
cgitb.enable()

# Output basic response
print 'content-type:text/plain'
print
print 'Hello World'
```

Then, I try to update the script to read in the request from **stdin**

```
import cgi, cgitb

# Detailed error logging to screen
cgitb.enable()

# Attempt to read the raw request from CGI
import sys
request = sys.stdin.read()

# Output basic response
print 'content-type:text/plain'
print
print 'Hello World'
```

Suddenly, I receive the following error: `<type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor` on the line containing `stdin.read()`.

**Question**:

Why is `stdin` considered a bad file?

Have I configured something incorrectly in IIS or is this a limitation to IIS?  Or, perhaps, is the fact that the request is delivered via stdin an incorrect assumption?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and discovered that under IIS, you need to use the CONTENT_LENGTH environment variable to bound the amount of data you read from stdin.  Here is what I added to my code to make it work on IIS7:

```
try:
    import os
    request = sys.stdin.read(int(os.environ['CONTENT_LENGTH']))
except:
    request = ''
```

Comment: I, unfortunately, no longer have access to the environment that I originally tested this in, but this definitely would have been an interesting thing to try (and something that I hadn't looked into the first time through)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late... but I think that `stdin` (fd 0) was closed.